# How to get attributes on a referenced field

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, fieldinfo

I have a question:
Is there an elegant way of getting Attributes on a referenced field.
Ie.:

```
public class C1: Base
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public string Field1;
}
public class Base
{
    private void Do(ref string field)
    {
          if (field has attributes)
              DoSomething();
    }
}
```

How can I get attributes of a field in the method Do()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way you can do that with `ref string field` signature. Attributes are applied to declarations (fields, classes, events etc.), not to "instances".

What you *can* do, is alter your method like this:

```
private void Do(Type fieldContainingType, string fieldName, ref string field)
```

and then use reflection to inspect `fieldContainingType` to see, what attributes are applied to field named `fieldName`. This approach, however, is extremely fragile and generally very bad.